# CSS on Menu Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My designer has given me these elements to work with when building the HTML elements.

All is good un till i get to the faint uneven borders on the LI tags. Especially on the one with only five li items.

If someone could show me the best way to achieve with SASS/CSS then that would be awesome! Have a look at the links provided. the rest of the styling is fine, just the small little border at uneven sizes. My desired effect was to have it as a fluid layout, so when you take the 6th li tag out of the unordered list it jumps from figure A to figure B.

My HTML so far,

```
<div class="full-screen-nav">
   <div class="container main-nav">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#clickme"><span class="menu_itemText">Products</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#"><span class="menu_itemText">Learn</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#"><span class="menu_itemText">Manage</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#"><span class="menu_itemText">Advice</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#"><span class="menu_itemText">News</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#"><span class="menu_itemText">Retirement</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and my SCSS

```
    // Universal Styles for Full Page nav elements
.full-screen-nav {
    background-color: $slate;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;

    ul {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

        li {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
    }

    .menu {
        font-size: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;

        .menu_item {
            font-size: 10pt;
            width: 33%;
            display: inline-block;
            color: #FFF;
            text-align: center;
            border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
            position: relative;

            .menu_itemText {
                padding: 100px 0px 10px 0px;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            &.menu_item:nth-child(3n){
                border-right: 0;
            }

            &.menu_item:nth-child(n+4){
                border-bottom: 0;
            }

            &.menu_item:nth-child(4):after, &.menu_item:nth-child(5):after {
                content: "";
                color: red;
                position: absolute;
                right: -16px;
                background: $slate;
                padding: 16px;
                top: -16px;
            }
        }
    }
    }

    //Unique Navigation
     .unique-nav {
    .container {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    h2 {
        background: url(#{$assets}/icons/chevron.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
    }

    .menu {
        li {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 70px;
            background-position: center 20px;

            &:first-child {background-image: url(#{$assets}/menu/products.svg) }
            &:nth-child(2) {background-image: url(#{$assets}/menu/products.svg) }
            &:nth-child(3) {background-image: url(#{$assets}/menu/manage.svg) }
            &:nth-child(4) {background-image: url(#{$assets}/menu/investments.svg) }
            &:nth-child(5) {background-image: url(#{$assets}/menu/news.png) }
            &:nth-child(6) {background-image: url(#{$assets}/menu/retirement.svg)   }
        }
    }
    }
```

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're using these as sprite sheets, just cut the sprite a pixel or two before the border so its included in the image?

Comment: can we see the actual code?

Comment: the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Comment: Important question. Should this be fluid layout?

Comment: Yes it needs to be a fluid layout :) @JanNahody

Comment: Why do questions like this get downvoted?

Comment: They get down voted because they basically translate to 'I haven't done anything can you do it all for me'

Comment: @samuelmr ahhh I see thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

OK, this looks quite confusing...but why not try this:

```
table { 
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I am not using tables and I am already using flexbox for the display attribute

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution which is fluid and use CSS only.
I use 4 span elements for each corner. More useful should be to use the pseudo elements :before and :after for the top corners and one span elements at bottom, again with 2 pseudo elements :before and :after for the bottom corners.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

.iconbox {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  
    display: -webkit-box;
  
    display: -webkit-flex;
  
    display: -ms-flexbox;
  
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
        -ms-flex-pack: start;
            justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
        -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
            align-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
        -ms-flex-align: start;
            align-items: flex-start;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.iconbox li {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
      -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
          align-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 100px;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 100px;
          flex: 1 1 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  margin: -2px;
}

.iconbox li .edges-top-right {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -3px;
  right: -2px;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
}

.iconbox li .edges-top-left {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -3px;
  left: -2px;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
}

.iconbox li .edges-bottom-right {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  z-index: 100;
}

.iconbox li .edges-bottom-left {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<ul class="iconbox">
  <li>
    <span class="edges-top-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-top-left"></span>
    Products
    <span class="edges-bottom-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-bottom-left"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="edges-top-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-top-left"></span>
    Learn
    <span class="edges-bottom-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-bottom-left"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="edges-top-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-top-left"></span>
    Manage
    <span class="edges-bottom-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-bottom-left"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="edges-top-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-top-left"></span>
    Advice
    <span class="edges-bottom-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-bottom-left"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="edges-top-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-top-left"></span>
    News
    <span class="edges-bottom-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-bottom-left"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="edges-top-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-top-left"></span>
    Retirement
    <span class="edges-bottom-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-bottom-left"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="edges-top-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-top-left"></span>
    Investments
    <span class="edges-bottom-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-bottom-left"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="edges-top-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-top-left"></span>
    Specials
    <span class="edges-bottom-right"></span>
    <span class="edges-bottom-left"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/jannahody/pen/dMqZXz)
Please play with the browser width to see the fluid effect.